# How to plot geo-referenced image so that it "fits" the plot coordinate system in Matplotlib

Tags: image, plot, matplotlib, cartography

A very similar question, solved the same way: [how to use 'extent' in matplotlib.pyplot.imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6999621/401828)

---

I have a list of geographical coordinates (a "tracklog") that describe a geographical trajectory. Also, I have the means of obtaining an image spanning the tracklog coverage, where I know the "geographical coordinates" of the corners of the image.

My plot currently looks like this (notice the ticks - x=longitudes, y=latitudes, in UTM, WGS84):

[image]

Then suppose I know the corner coordinates of the following image (or a version of it without the blue track), and would like to plot it SO THAT IT FITS THE COORDINATE SYSTEM of the plot.

[image]

How would I do it?

(as a side note, in case that matters, I plan to use tiles)

---

As per the comment of Joe Kington (waiting for his actual answer so that I can accept it), the following code works as expected, giving a pannable and zoomable fixed-aspect "georeferenced" tile over which I am able to plot tracklogs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Image
import numpy

imarray = numpy.asarray(Image.open('map.jpg'))

plt.plot([0,1], [0,1], 'o', c='red', ms=20)  ## some reference circles for debugging
plt.imshow(imarray, extent=[0,1,0,1])   ## some random map whose corners have known coordinates
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to project it (you mention UTM and geographic coordinates) or just how to plot an image with specified extents?  (If it's the latter, just use the `extents` kwarg to `imshow`.)

Comment: @JoeKington I'd like to just plot, since the image is already "projected" (its grid is the same as the plot grid). I'm take a look at `extents`, but if you could post a working answer I'd gladly accept it!

Comment: From what I see, `extents` adjusts the axes to the image, and not the opposite. I'm trying something with OffsetImage as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4860777/401828

Comment: No, it just calls `axis(image)` after plotting, which makes it appear that way. Just specify `aspect = "auto"` to imshow and either plot the image first, or reset thelimits of the axes after plotting the image. (it's easiest to just plot it first). I'm posing this from a phone, or else I'd give a full example. Offset image is for when you want the size of the image to be in display coordinates. hope that helps a bit, anyway!

Comment: @JoeKington It helps, but I'll need time to fully grasp it too. Thanks for now!

Answer (score 0):

There is really not much of an answer here, but if you are using matplotlib, and you geos-tuff, take a look at [matplotlib.basemap](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/).
By default all operations are done on UTM maps, but you can choose your own projection.
Take also a look on the list of good tutorials in http://www.geophysique.be, [for example](http://www.geophysique.be/2010/05/05/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-part-03-masked-arrays-zoom/).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by taking a screenshot from some maps program and then finding out the lat/lon borders of the image. I can imshow the whole map and the use `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` to only show the area I want to.

Since the maps in navigation programs are plot maps in a 1km:1km aspect ratio, you have to manually set that ratio using the sinus of the latitude.

```py
from PIL import Image

munich_map = Image.open("images/munich-map.png")

...

axis.imshow(
   munich_map,
   extent=[11.245921, 11.930659, 47.949627, 48.279644],
   aspect=1 / math.sin(math.radians(48)),
)

axis.set_xlim(from_lon, to_lon)
axis.set_ylim(from_lat, to_lat)
```

[image]