# how to plot new data on an image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imread

I have a calculated data (x,y) which I would like to put on top of an image from a paper to compare with some of its boundaries. If this image was a 2D x,y plot, I would have extracted easily the points and then plot together with mine. However this image is a 3D color plot, therefore if I want just to read the image, define my coordinates according to it and plot my data on top, so at the end would seem like 2 layers.

I can plot scatter points by following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = plt.imread('fig_exp.png')
implot = plt.imshow(im)

# put a blue dot at (10, 20)
plt.scatter([10], [20], c='r', s=2000, marker=u'*')

plt.show()
```

But how can I define image coordinates so I can plot e.g

```
x=[-100,-80,-60,-40]
y=[10,15,20,25]
plt.plot(x,y,'-ro')
```

[image]

The problem here is that I dont know how to define the coordinates as in the figure. Beside I dont know how to plot not as scatter but a line.

I appreciate any helpful solution!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use 'extent' in matplotlib.pyplot.imshow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999621/how-to-use-extent-in-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `extent=` keyword argument to `imshow()` as detailed in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)

As for your second question, if you want a line plot, you use the `plot()` function instead of `scatter()`.

Comment: Great! I am getting to the right answer, e.g by here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999621/how-to-use-extent-in-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow