# How to set axes in python?

Tags: python, plot, axes, astropy, fits

I'm plotting a .fits image using the next code

```
signal_filt = fits.open('signal_filt.fits')[0]
wcs = WCS(signal_filt.header)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], projection=wcs)
lqs = ax.imshow(signal_filt.data, vmin = -1,  vmax = 4, cmap = 'hot',origin = 'lower')
ax.imshow(signal_filt.data[y1:y2,x1:x2]*1000, vmin = -1,  vmax = 4, cmap = 'hot', origin = 'lower')
cb = plt.colorbar(lqs)
cb.set_label('Flux (mJy/beam)')
```

but I want to set the axes as follow: in the coordinate positions (wcs, centered in a specific star) hh:mm:ss and dd:mm:ss I want to set a zero, since there to left side I want to set negative values, while to the right side I want to set positive values, and in the same way upward and downward directions. 
[Like this example, the zero coordinates is settled in a specific place, and axes shows "deltas"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0isw.png)

Can anyone can help me?

Comment: I might be missing something, but why not use just use [APLpy](https://aplpy.github.io/) for plotting FITS files?

Comment: perhaps see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999621/how-to-use-extent-in-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow.  Or manually change the tick values.  @VlasSokolov aplpy unfortunately does not (yet) implement offset coordinates: https://github.com/aplpy/aplpy/issues/31

Answer (score 1):

maybe using :

```
ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
```

or

```
x1,x2,y1,y2 = plt.axis()
plt.axis((x1,x2,y1,y2))
```