# Why does imshow's extent argument flip my images?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 16

im = np.eye(n)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.imshow(im)
ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax.imshow(im, extent=(0, n, 0, n))

plt.show()
```

results in the following figure
[image]

I would have expected that with this `extent`, both figures are (almost) identical, but they are not: note how the y-axis is flipped. What's more annoying is that the figure on the right is wrong: the value at the origin is show as 0 whereas it is one.

If I flip the y argument in the extent, `extent=(0, n, n, 0)`, I get the expected behavior.

As I understand it, the description of the `extent` argument of [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow),

> **extent** : scalars (left, right, bottom, top), optional, default: `None`
>
> The location, in data-coordinates, of the lower-left and upper-right corners. If `None`, the image is positioned such that the pixel centers fall on zero-based (row, column) indices.

is not really explicit about that behavior.

My question is, why does this flip happen, why do we have to invert top/bottom in the extent to get the expected behavior?

**EDIT**

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999621/how-to-use-extent-in-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow), the OP does not mention a flipping issue and the answer does not bring the issue either.

Setting `origin='lower'` element does bring the first image pixel at `(0,0)` but the image is then displayed upside down.

I am sure there is a simple explanation to explain these behaviors consistently but quite can't pin it yet.

Comment: It's probably because the image is drawn left-to-right and top-to-bottom. So `top=n` and `bottom=0` is "bottom-up".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `imshow` has an argument `origin`. The default is `origin="upper"`. This conflicts with the setting of the `extent`, which, according to the documentation, should set the "location, in data-coordinates, of the lower-left and upper-right corners." This, however is only true if `origin = "lower"` is set.

I [have already proposed](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8693#issuecomment-305360175) to extend the documentation with a sentence like

> "If you set origin to "upper" any y coordinates you may specify using extent and/or ylim need to be reversed."

This is exactly what you already found out yourself. So options are:

- If you want the image to origin in the upper left corner:

  ```
  origin="upper", extent=(0, n, n, 0)
  ```
- If you want the image to origin in the lower left corner:

  ```
  origin="lower", extent=(0, n, 0, n)
  ```

Comment: Thanks. However, both options are not equivalent: the image is displayed upside down in the second option.

Comment: Yes, sure. But they show the data correctly, right? It's up to you to decide which orientation you prefer.

Comment: Absolutely. I was suggesting to add this precision because as it is, one could think you are suggesting both options behave similarly.

Comment: You didn't say which version you prefer, so both are valid. You may propose an edit to my answer if you think it needs refinition.