# Python - plotting 2D array but need the indices to correspond to coordinates. How do I do this?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have an array of 2D data that I'd like to plot using `imshow()`. Since my data is in a 2D array, it's indexed as 0-300 x 0-300. However, the real data translates to physical X,Y coordinates. So, the value at `arr[0,0]` would actually correspond to the value at X,Y coordinate (-3,-3). I'm not sure how to properly plot that so that the axes of my plot range from (-3 to 3) as opposed to (0 to 300).

I'm using matplotlib and Python.

Comment: Use the `extent` keyword of `imshow`. Also check existing questions on that topic.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`imshow` comes with `extent` which solves your problem, you can read about how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999621/how-to-use-extent-in-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow).